# SQLite trim end characters from string

Tags: sql, sqlite, trim, substr

Using SQLite.

```
ltrim(ltrim(substr(tablename.time, 11),'0123456789'),'-') as main_time
```

I have the above `trim` function which removes the first 11 characters from my string below.

```
2013-10-28 09:29:57.987 -- Original String.
09:29:57.987            -- New String.
```

However I'd still like to remove the last four characters from the end of the string, turning it into the below:

```
09:29:57
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `LENGTH`:

```
SUBSTR(your_string, 1,LENGTH(your_string)-4)
```

However, in your case is just specify fixed positions:

```
SUBSTR(tablename.time, 12, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the time from such a string, just use the [time function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
time(tablename.time)
```