# Remove last n chars of a varchar column

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to know if there's a "compact" way of deleting last n chars from a column in PostGreSQL.

I have a column born as a DATE formatted like this: yyyy-MM-dd.

I altered the table to make this column a varchar, replaced all of the unnecessary dashes but I can't think about a quick and reliable way to delete the last two chars since I'd like the varchar to show only yyyyMM.

With "quick and reliable" I mean something that won't ask me to use a temp table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first mistake was converting a date to a varchar/string as there are a [healthy number of functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) [for dealing with date formatting on date types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) `to_char(your_original_date_field, 'YYYYMM')` for instance would do this quickly. Furthermore it sounds like you original date (with the unnecessary dashes) was in ISO 8601 notation which is pretty standard... being that it's the standard.

Comment: technically, this substitution could be done for example with `substring(myCol from 1 for length(myCol)-2)` (in an `update` statement)

Comment: @JNevill well I was using to_char and cast but since our platform opened to other services that treat dates as strings I needed to make things standard just to avoid future crashes ;)

Comment: Changing a `date` field to a `VARCHAR` is going to cause problems down the line: If you need to expose your dates as text, you should create a VIEW that uses `TO_CHAR` or `CAST`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`left()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), e.g.:

```
select 
    left('20181004', 6),    -- get 6 leftmost characters
    left('20181004', -2)    -- or remove 2 last ones

  left  |  left  
--------+--------
 201810 | 201810
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to highlight a version of [ewcz's suggestion from a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647648/remove-last-n-chars-of-a-varchar-column#comment92227275_52647648)
 a bit more

```
substr(myCol, 1, length(myCol) - 2)
```

as that is more portable across RDMSs (not sure if ANSI though).

E.g. SQLite does not have a [`LEFT` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648417/895245).

This is also suggested on the followint SQLite question: [SQLite trim end characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654365/sqlite-trim-end-characters-from-string)

Tested on PostgreSQL 14, SQLite 3.37.2, Ubuntu 22.04.

Google, index this: "remove suffix".

Comment: in postgres there is no length, instead there is: char_length ( text ) → integer

character_length ( text ) → integer

Returns number of characters in the string.

char_length('josé') → 4

Comment: @OmarAziz `length(` is documented at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html and worked locally